# Adding new form inputs continuously

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I currently have a form where an individual can add firstname and lastname via two input fields. In some scenarios they may want to add more 
than one so I want to provide button/bit of text below that if they click will create another firstname and lastname input field to add the 
information.  Ideally I would like this to repeat indefinately and they could always just keep adding as many as they want but I know thats
a bit unrealistic so if I settled for giving them the ability to add 10 firstnames and lastnames I would be happy.  Im just wondering if I could
accomplish this in angular and if so what would be the best method to do this? make use of a directory and ng-repeat or something along those
lines?  I would also like a bit of text which would simply remove the specified firstname / lastname input if clicked.

I would appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this if it is possible (im not asking for anyone to go ahead and code it), more just
guidelines on how I could accomplish this. Just cant seem to think of the best way to do it in my head.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible,

In your controller, to make things a bit more structured you could have something like

```
var name = function (first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

$scope.names = [new name()]; // start off with one firstname + lastname
$scope.addName = function () {
    $scope.names.push(new name()); // add a blank name
}
```

And the corresponding html;

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name.first" placeholder="firstname"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name.last" placeholder="lastname"/>
</div>
<button ng-click="addName()"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it really helped me out.  Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is definitely possible, and it is probably easier to do the infinite one than a specific number of inputs.

For the javascript code in the angular controller I would have an array with the names to be added. starting with and empty array, then a function that would add to that array:

```
$scope.namesToAdd=[];
$scope.moreNames=function(){
  namesToAdd.push({first:'',sirname:''});
};
```

Then for the html code it would be something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat-start="names in namesToAdd" ng-model="names.first">
<input type="text" ng-repeat-end ng-model="names.sirname">
<button ng-click="moreNames()">Add more names</button>
```